# Can't get SSL configuration working on Google Cloud Compute Engine

Tags: wordpress, ssl, certbot

I configured SSL for multiple Click to Deploy WordPress sites using the methodology explained in this [blogpost](https://www.onepagezen.com/free-ssl-certificate-wordpress-google-cloud-click-to-deploy/).

It worked great for 3 of them however, when I go to set it up on this [blog](http://sterlingsmith.me/) it completes the process but does not take. I've uninstalled Certbot and re-installed it. 
I've checked my `chmod` permissions and made sure most of the file structure is set to `777`. 
I've restarted the server after all this, of course. Basically, is there some limitation within Certbot that I am unaware of that makes it unable to handle non dot-com domains? The URL is hosted in Google Domains. Is there an alternative method that I can try?

Comment: Figured it out. It WAS a GCP issue but it was a issue with the firewall settings

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was the firewall settings. The firewall was blocking https traffic.